# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X_train' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, local, unbound

```
def CreateData(self, n_samples, seed_in=5, 
        train_prop=0.9, bound_limit=6., n_std_devs=1.96,**kwargs):

        np.random.seed(seed_in)
        scale_c=1.0 # default
        shift_c=1.0
        
        # for ideal boundary
        X_ideal = np.linspace(start=-bound_limit,stop=bound_limit, num=50000)
        y_ideal_U = np.ones_like(X_ideal)+1. # default
        y_ideal_L = np.ones_like(X_ideal)-1.
        y_ideal_mean = np.ones_like(X_ideal)+0.5

        if self.type_in[:1] == '~':
            if self.type_in=="~boston":
                path = 'boston_housing_data.csv'
                data = np.loadtxt(path,skiprows=0)
            elif self.type_in=="~concrete":
                path = 'Concrete_Data.csv'
                data = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
            elif self.type_in=="~wind":
                path = '/content/Deep_Learning_Prediction_Intervals/code/canada_CSV.csv'
                data = np.loadtxt(path,delimiter=',',skiprows=1,usecols = (1,2)) ## CHECK WHTHER TO HAVE LOADTXT OR ANYTHING ELSE PARUL
            
            
            # work out normalisation constants (need when unnormalising later)
            scale_c = np.std(data[:,-1])
            shift_c = np.mean(data[:,-1])

            # normalise data for ALL COLUMNS
            for i in range(0,data.shape[1]): ## i varies from 0 to number of columns ,means it reads one by one the columns
                # avoid zero variance features (exist one or two)
#               nonlocal X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val ## ADDED BY PARUL
                sdev_norm = np.std(data[:,i])
                sdev_norm = 0.001 if sdev_norm == 0 else sdev_norm
                data[:,i] = (data[:,i] - np.mean(data[:,i]) )/sdev_norm

            # split into train/test
            perm = np.random.permutation(data.shape[0]) ## DO THE DATA PERMUTATION OF ALL THE ROWS (shuffle)
            train_size = int(round(train_prop*data.shape[0]))
            train = data[perm[:train_size],:]
            test = data[perm[train_size:],:]
            
            
            y_train = train[:,-1].reshape(-1,1) ## LAST COLUMN IS CONSIDERED AS THE TARGET AND RESHAPED IN BETWEEN -1,1
            X_train = train[:,:-1] ## INPUTS ARE ALL EXCEPT LAST COLUMN
            y_val = test[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)
            X_val = test[:,:-1]

            # save important stuff
            self.X_train = X_train
            self.y_train = y_train
            self.X_val = X_val
            self.y_val = y_val
            self.X_ideal = X_ideal
            self.y_ideal_U = y_ideal_U
            self.y_ideal_L = y_ideal_L
            self.y_ideal_mean = y_ideal_mean
            self.scale_c = scale_c
            self.shift_c = shift_c

        return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val
```

It gives me an error
'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X_train' referenced before assignment'

Any help will be appreciated. I am stuck at this. I have tried initialising X_train with X_train=[] and also tried making them global, but didn't get any result. Please help me so that I could move forward.

Comment: `X_train` is set `if self.type_in[:1] == '~'`. But you try to return it even if this is not the case. Maybe it's enough if you initialize it at the start of the function with an appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I removed this line and now code is working fine.